# iOS/Swift: Making the source code of an app visible?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Is it possible/do you know any possibility to visualize the source code of an app? Because I'm working on something and I have got an app that does exactly what I want mine to do, just in a completely different way. Basically, every app on the AppStore has to be written in Xcode, right? So how do I visualize the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you searched for `Swift visualise code`? That search finds this: https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/objc-dependency-visualizer

Comment: There's no way to get the source code from an app on the app store unless the developer of that app has decided to make the source available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The developer needs to share the code with you if you want to get the full code. 
You **can't** extract the code from the .ipa itself (which is essentially the app)

Moreover, not every iOS app is written in Xcode - you have other SDK to write Swift and Objective-C with and more apps that you can write cross platform app with that eventually produced the .ipa file.